# Xcode- Constraints not being applied in viewdidappear

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

my constraints that I set programmatically in viewdidappear doesn't get applied in some of my views when first loaded, but when I change tabs and come back, it sets them after displaying the views. This happens in my popover view and collection view. Maybe it has something to do with me changing the popover view's width and height in viewdidlaod. Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks

```
unlockedDateLabelTrailingCipad.constant = -(imageView.frame.size.width * 0.08)
```

Comment: Why not putting your constraints into viewDidLoad ?

Comment: call view.layoutIfNeeded() after this code\

Comment: view.layoutIfNeeded() didn't work for some reason. And the views' frames aren't correct yet in viewdidload, they get set after it. I used a timer to call a function to set the constraints after displaying and it worked. But I'm still curious why this issue occurs

Comment: Try it in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method.

Comment: Cool, that worked!